# Get list of available devices in Firebase Test Lab

Tags: android, firebase, continuous-integration, gcloud, firebase-test-lab

I try to use following command to get list of available devices:

```
gcloud beta test android devices list
```

I need it to create testing device matrix `YML` config file. I checked it [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/emulators/), but not found right command. I found above command in a tutorial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for `gcloud firebase test android models list`?